# WebRTC: ios app development

Tags: ios, webrtc

I am in the process of writing up a native ios app to add our web app, I am doing research on ios webrtc app development.

I could only see information from OpenTok which is a freemium model, this could be used for the first 10k minutes which will take a while to run out as we building this for healthcare providers in the UK.

I wanted to see if there was any other way to write an ios webrtc app without using any third party libraries/sdks.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the native [WebRTC API](http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/)...or you could write your own webrtc connection logic yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The link provided by Fan Jin and Dr. Alex are outdated.
here is up to date info (Feb 2018)

The best choice to start a webrtc app on iOS is to use the official sample app : https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/objc/AppRTCMobile/

Since it's not so easy to build it with Xcode, it can be easier to start from https://github.com/crossle/AppRTCMobile. It's based on February 2018 webrtc code.

you just have to take the project, compile it and install the perfectly working app on your iPhone.

It's using the apprtc signalling server. The source is at https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc.

If you want to try to create your own Xcode project, the best is to use cocoaPods lib from google: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC

Answer (score 0):

- opentok is NOT a fermium model, you pay 50 Dollars up front, in which 10k "free" mms are included (which makes the cost of those 0.5 cents). [here](https://tokbox.com/pricing).
- opentok is charging for "streamed minutes" and not cumulated minutes. For example, in a 10 mn call with 5 participants, you spend 50 cumulated minutes, and 200 streamed minutes [n*(n-1)*t]. If you plan to have multiparty calls, opentok can become expensive. Note that if you are recording, the recording count as one. That means, if you have a 10 persons call for 10 mn, instead of paying n*(n-1)*t, you will pay (n+1)*n*t, and extra 2*n*t minutes (extra 200 mn here).
- you have several PaaS that will propose cumulated minutes
- you can set up  your own server and not pay anything (only interesting if your volume is low).

to answer more specifically your question:

- you can go take a look at the native implementations (webrtc.org, openwebrtc.io) and pick up their iOS demo (appRTCDemo in the first case) for your use.
- Note that you would still need a back-end. One is provided with appRTCDemo based on google compute engine, but you would still need to set it up. I'm less familiar with openWebRTC yet.

Comment: Hey Alex, thank you very much for the transparent advice. I found some ios webrtc app demos on github which I will pick up for my use. I also found some SDK for ios which are in beta as of November 2014. Will definitely spend some time to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install [WebRTC CocoaPod](https://github.com/Anakros/WebRTC) in your project so you don't have to build the ios-webrtc yourself.

There are plenty good examples on Github which demonstrate how to use the native iOS library. I leant a lot from repository like: [aoortc-ios](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios).

Answer (score 0):

RTC is real time communication protocol over https, at end point 2 or more party’s can connect and they can chat, send file, call or video call.

You can enable RTC protocol and write your own code over iOS, Web and Android to enable this feature. There will be only cost of your server maintainance. And you will have entire control over systems without any third party with no cost.